# How to Import Students List in a Multi-Column ListView in C#?

Tags: c#, listview

I want to import the list of Student, DOB, Location into ListView1

My code results in a "Nil" value, been trying to fix from several hours with no luck

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>() {
            new Student() { name = "AAA", dob = DateTime.ParseExact("10-05-2000", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), location = "Mumbai"},
            new Student() { name = "BBB", dob = DateTime.ParseExact("05-02-2000", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), location = "Pune"},
            new Student() { name = "CCC", dob = DateTime.ParseExact("01-01-2000", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), location = "Delhi"},
            new Student() { name = "DDD", dob = DateTime.ParseExact("20-03-1999", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), location = "Lucknow"},
            new Student() { name = "EEE", dob = DateTime.ParseExact("15-06-1999", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), location = "Chennai"},
            new Student() { name = "FFF", dob = DateTime.ParseExact("18-09-1999", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), location = "Ahmedabad"}
        };


        var results = students.OrderByDescending(x => x.dob)  //sort from youngest to oldest
            .GroupBy(x => x.dob.Year) //group by year
            .Select(x => x.First())  //get first student born each year which is youngest
            .ToList();

        listView1.Items.Clear();
        int counterOfArraylist = results.Count;
        string[] str = new string[counterOfArraylist];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) { str[i] = results[i].ToString(); }
        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(str)); 

    }
}

public class Student
{
    public DateTime dob { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to `results[i].ToString();` to work as expected, you should override the `ToString()` method of your class and return the value you like:

```
public class Student
{
    public DateTime dob { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name + " - " + dob.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")+ " - " +location;
    }
}
```

Or just add it inline in your code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) { str[i] = return name + " - " + dob.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")+ " - " +location; }
```

if you want each property in a separate column then you can simply do something like this:

```
ListViewItem[] items = results
   .Select(x => new ListViewItem(new string[]{x.name, x.dob.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"), x.location})
    .ToArray();

listView1.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sir. Tried both but C# shows below errors:

1) Unexpected character '$'
2) Invalid expression term "
3) ; expected (3 times)
4) Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
5) The type or namespace name 'MMM' could not be found
6) Only assignment, call, ........


Is it bcz I'm using C# 2008 version?

Comment: @NamitVerma it is because your c# version is low and does not support interpolated strings. I edited my answer please have a look.

Comment: Thanks so much Sir... Really greatful..

First two codes are working but I want each property in separate column, so I tried your 3rd code.. but it shows this error: "System.Array does not contain a definition for ToArray"

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad... ")" was missing, corrected it and it works  :)  Lemme search for a way to upvote your answer... Thanks a lot